# Filter XML file

Tags: jquery, xml, filter

i would like to filter my xml file. XML looks like that:

```
<o id="17" url="url" price="15.00" avail="1" weight="0" stock="3" set="0" 
basket="0">
<cat><![CDATA[ category ]]></cat>
<name><![CDATA[ name ]]></name>
<imgs><main url="url"/></imgs>
<desc><![CDATA[description]]></desc>
<attrs><a name="text"><![CDATA[ Dev ]]></a>
<a name="Code"><![CDATA[ ]]></a>
<a name="EAN"><![CDATA[ EAN ]]></a>
</attrs>

<o id="18" url="url" price="15.00" avail="1" weight="0" stock="3" set="0" 
basket="0">
<cat><![CDATA[ category2 ]]></cat>
<name><![CDATA[ name ]]></name>
<imgs><main url="url"/></imgs>
<desc><![CDATA[description]]></desc>
<attrs><a name="text"><![CDATA[ Dev ]]></a>
<a name="Code"><![CDATA[ ]]></a>
<a name="EAN"><![CDATA[ EAN ]]></a>
</attrs>
```

I would like to filter every product (o id) by category, so if product got category2 show all structure of this product. Is it possible to get with XPath?

Answer (score 0):

Using XPath you select `//o[normalize-space(cat) = 'category2']`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are genius.